# How to format a number into NN.nn style

Tags: micropython

I am handling a stream of numbers from sensors and want to format them to a 'standard' layout centered on the decimal point, as per the following: 1.00  = 01.00 | 12.9  = 12.90 | 2     = 02.00 | 49.09 = 49.09 etc.

I have tried zfill and round - including combinations but the decimal point moves in everything I have tried so far. The purpose is to fill pre-defined fields for later analysis.

*UPDATE*
Probably not the most elegant solution but I came up with this, which works a far as I have been able to test so far:

For padding to the left of decimal point:

```
def zfl(d, chrs, pad):
 # Pads the provided string with leading 'pad's to suit the specified 
 # 'chrs' length.
 # When called, parameters are : d = string, chrs = required length of 
 # string and pad = fill characters
 # The formatted string of correct length and added pad characters is 
 # returned as string
 frmtd_str = str(d)
 while len(frmtd_str) != chrs:
     # less then required characters
     frmtd_str = pad + frmtd_str
 return(frmtd_str)`
```

Function for padding to the right of decimal point:

```
def zfr(d, chrs, pad):
# Pads the provided string with trailing 'pad's to suit the specified 
# 'chrs' length
# When called, parameters are : d = string, chrs = required length of 
# string and pad = fill characters
# The formatted string of correct length and added pad characters is 
# returned as string
frmtd_str = str(d)
while len(frmtd_str) != chrs:
    # less then required characters
    frmtd_str = frmtd_str + pad
return(frmtd_str)
```

Example to call the above funtions:

The original data is split into two parts using the decimal as the seperator:

dat_splt = str(Dat[0]).split(".",2)

Then the padding carried out and reconstructed for use:

exampledat = "{}.{}".format(zfl(dat_splt[0],3,'0'), zfr(dat_splt[1],3,'0'))

Notes:

1. To pad out either side requires the parameters for string, character required and the 'pad' character.
2. The characters required can be anything (only tested with 1 to 10)
3. The final returned string can be asymmetrical i.e.  nnnnn.nn  or n.nnn
4. The number of characters in each part of the original data is accommodated.

Quite happy with the results from this and it is reusable as common functions. I am sure there are more 'economical/efficient' methods but I haven't found those yet and at least this works, giving nice orderly and stable text string result lists (which is what I was aiming for at this point).

Hope I got the layout correct..  :-)

Comment: Numbers do not have leading zeros. Strings may be left-padded with zeros, but `01.00` is not a number.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I know that, and was wanting to convert the numbers into strings of a fixed format, with leading and trailing zero padding as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'{:0>5.2f}'.format(n)

```
'{:0>5.2f}'.format(1)
'01.00'
'{:0>5.2f}'.format(12.9)
'12.90'
'{:0>5.2f}'.format(49.09)
'49.09'
```

https://queirozf.com/entries/python-number-formatting-examples#left-padding-with-zeros